# Prove/show the expected value of a transformed gamma distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

UNDERGRADUATE PROBABILITY ~
In the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967601/expected-value-of-the-gamma-distribution) I'm having trouble understanding what is going on between the first and second line of the answer. I was studying the answer to show $ E(Y^c) = \frac{\beta^c \Gamma(\alpha+c)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$ so I can't copy the solution because I'm not sure how $ u = x/\beta $ came about in the linked answer. My calculus is a bit rusty that might be why?

Comment: Just $\beta^{\alpha+1}$ has been factored out. Clear now?

Comment: Please see if my self-posted answer is correct:

Comment: Which answer, Five9?

Comment: Lol took longer than I expected to type out sorry. Here it is now below.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question after I figured it out:

To show that $E(Y^c) = \frac{\beta^{c}\Gamma(a+c)}{\Gamma(a)}$ use the E(X) formula
$$
E(Y^c)=\int{y^c P(y)=\int{y^{c}\frac{1}{\beta^a \Gamma(a)}y^{a-1}e^{-y/\beta}dy}}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\beta^{\alpha} \Gamma(\alpha)}\int{y^{\alpha+c-1} e^{-y/\beta} dy}
$$
Here's where I made a mistake: I also gave the exponential's $y$ a $c$, making it $e^{-y/\beta}$ when it doesn't need it. I was trying to factor this in the next steps which was impossible...Let $ u = \frac{y}{\beta}$ and thus $du/dy=\frac{y}{\beta}$
$$
=\frac{\beta^{a+c-1+1}}{\beta^{\alpha} \Gamma(\alpha)}
\int{(\frac{y}{\beta})^{\alpha+c-1} e^{-y/\beta}\frac{1}{\beta}dy}
$$
Substitute u's and simplify the coefficient:
$$
=\frac{\beta^{c}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}
\int{(u)^{\alpha+c-1} e^{-u}du}
$$
And following the definition of a gamma function, the integral is just a gamma function with parameter a+c:
$$
=\frac{\beta^{c}\Gamma(a+c)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}
$$

-Sorry not sure how to left-align and adjust those brackets to full size lmao

Comment: Wait jokes that was stupid I got it.

Comment: Really? What was the mistake?

Comment: I was struggling to get my last equation to look like a gamma function $\Gamma(\alpha) = \int_0^\infty{x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x} dx}$ but my goal was to find $E(Y^c)$ so I just failed to see that $\alpha-1+c$ was literally what I needed (if $\alpha$ was replaced with $\alpha-1$) it just looked weird since the $-1$ was before the $c$. I'm going to clean up this thread in a bit so it's more clear.

Comment: I´m looking forward to see what you found out.

Comment: If you need help leave a comment.

Comment: Sorry was rushing to finish the assignment :) Here it is, lmk how it looks

Comment: It looks fine, Five9. You see I just have been waiting all the hours for your answer.